# System.QueryException in aggregateResults

Tags: apex, soql, query

I am trying to run this query in apex and run into following error.

```
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [select Campaign__r.id cid, Count(opportunity__c) oppcount, FORMAT(SUM(Opportunity__r.Amount)) oppAmt from Campaign_influence__c where opportunity__c!=null AND Campaign__c in :CampaignList group by Campaign__r.id ];
```

> System.QueryException: Invalid field: 'Opportunity__r':

This query does run fine in developer console 'query editor'. It also works if I replace `FORMAT(SUM(Opportunity__r.Amount))` with just `SUM(Opportunity__r.amount)`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you confirm `Opportunity__c` is a lookup field to the `Opportunity` object?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Hi @shilpa, which API version you are using in that Apex class? Actually this feature is introduced in Spring'16 (API version 36.0 and later). https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring_%252716/formatting

Comment: yes I am on api version 38

Answer (score 3):

The `User` you are running this query as almost certainly lacks read permission on the `Opportunity__c` field. Navigate to their Profile configuration (`Setup` > `Manage Users` > `Profiles`) and go to `Object Settings` > `Campaign Influence`. Make sure they have `Read Access` selected for `Opportunity`.

What you're trying to do should be supported otherwise. The documentation on [`FORMAT()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_format.htm) states it supports aliasing and can be nested with aggregate functions:

> The FORMAT function supports aliasing. In addition, aliasing is required when the query includes the same field multiple times. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate, FORMAT(LastModifiedDate) formattedDate FROM Account
> ```
>
> You can also nest it with aggregate or convertCurrency() functions. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT amount, FORMAT(amount) Amt, convertCurrency(amount) editDate, FORMAT(convertCurrency(amount)) convertedCurrency FROM Opportunity where id = '12345'
> SELECT FORMAT(MIN(closedate)) Amt FROM opportunity
> ```

Comment: I have access to the field. This query runs fine in apex as well when i replace FORMAT(SUM(Opportunity__r.Amount)) with just SUM(Opportunity__r.amount). I guess it has something to do with the currency formatting?

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I avoided using FORMAT() and achieved what i needed by defining the fields in currency type instead of number fields. I am surprised salesforce failed to support what it has listed here https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring_%252716/formatting. Thanks again for all your responses.